# Import css into style/theme

Tags: java, css, vaadin, material-design-lite

I'm looking in to replacing the [Polymer Elements](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/elements-add-on) add-on with the [Material Designs Lite](https://www.getmdl.io/index.html) (MDL) css/js library so that I can design my layouts with more native components for Vaadin.

I've found accessing internal nodes for Polymer Elements to be a huge challenge, for example, the [Paper-Card](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-card) has internal divs for card-content, card-actions, etc.  It can be difficult to set the content or actions of a Card with a native Vaadin component as they are built more closely to html's tree structure using getRoot() and appendChild(), I can't just use addComponent(new Card()), not to mention design and layout can get difficult to coordinate.  So I'd rather have a consistent standard to styling and using components than having to worry if I'm using a Polymer vs Vaadin component.

So the idea is if I replace with MDL, then I should be able to apply the styling of Materials to Vaadin UI objects without the overhead of creating Elements and importing the Polymer html components.

However, I have an issue importing the required css it seems.  I have added the javascript library to my UI class and confirmed it is included using dev tools in Chrome.  But the styling fails to apply.  Is there an issue with importing css into the styles.scss?

**styles.scss**

```
@import "https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.2/material.indigo-pink.min.css"
@import "../valo.css"
....
```

Or is there another method for accomplishing my end goal of using Materials design with Vaadin that is simpler and easier to work with then the above?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The material.css needs to be renamed to use the scss file type.  (material.css -> material.scss) then is imported correctly.